# Values In Timestamp Field Displayed In Hex (0x000000000000000866) On Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table where I save emails that have been sent. I decided then to add a TimeStamp field to this table so I can track when the e-mail had been sent. Data is being written to the table with out any issues, but when I go to view the table contents using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, the data contained within the Timestamp field is displayed like this: 0x000000000000000000845, even  in records that have been written to the database since the Timestamp value was introduced

I then changed the field type to datetime, and it then displays a date. But it displays the date 1900-01-01 00:00:23 for example. I then changed it back to the Timestamp field, and it returned back in to it's current Hexadecimal format.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I decided then to add a TimeStamp
>   field to this table so I can track
>   when the e-mail had been sent

Ah yes. Reading teh database would have shown you that the TMIestamp field - which is a legacy from Sybase server -does NOT store a timestamp. Basically it is something like a global operations counter. It has NO relation to time.

If you want a real timestamp, put in a DateTime type of column and set the system time as default / through atrigger etc. Timestamp is totally unsuiteable for that.

Again, no a MS thing - MS SQL Server started as Sybase SQL Server port for windows, and the Timestampdata type is a Sybase legacy.

Comment: And the datatype `timestamp` has been deprecated in favour of `rowversion` which is indeed a much better description of what it really is

Comment: Good to know that it all started with sybase SQL Server. Naming is actually one of the toughest things in computer science. This is a very good example where timestamp has nothing to do with date and time :)